# Connection to the internet

Tags: internet

so for the last week or so I have been having problems with connecting to the internet. so when i get onto my mac everything is fine the connection to the internet is perfectly fine but it will randomly stop and disconnect me from a web page and I need skype for business and it also will just go offline randomly I have no idea how to fix this problem and i need help!

Comment: Can you give more details, and describe what happens more?

Comment: so Im connected to the internet and while im trying to load a page or load safari or google chrome the web page will have a message saying no internet connection and the wireless has full bars but it won't let me connect to any web pages or skype when im on skype it will just go from online to offline randomly

Comment: How are you connected to the internet? Are there other computers/smart phones in your flat which show similar (or no) problems?

Comment: I have my roommates who have and each of them have labtops but they show no problems and I'm using the desktop pc but it is having problems too I have it connected to our wireless with a wireless adapter but it will randomly not load pages and it will go offline so i don't know if i should reset the modem or buy a new wireless adapter and for my labtop i have no idea what to do because the wireless works for them but not for me

Answer (score 1):

Run `/System/Library/CoreServices/Network Diagnostics` and it will guide you through the steps to isolate any failure of the network services and infrastructure.

Once you have a specific failure mode, that could be asked as a follow on question here with that detail provided for the best chance we can assist you.